# Как перевести приложение в IOS Simulator в фоновый режим ? - Objective-C

Tags: ios

Здравствуйте, я изучаю Objective C. Мне нужно, чтобы управление передалось в метод

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackgroundUIApplication *)application

для этого тестируемое приложение на симуляторе нужно перевести в фоновый режим. Как это сделать ? Там нет кнопки свернуть...

Answer (score 1):

Можно перейти так:
**Simulator -> Hardware -> Home**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое !